# Payment reference

Tags: transactions, payment

Let's imagine I am hosting an online shop. I sell five different items with a price of 1 BTC.

Bob buys item A and Alice buys items B. Bob is paying the bill by sending 1 BTC to my Bitcoin address. Alice decides not to pay anything.

Now here is the big question: How do I know that I have received the money from Bob and not from Alice (I don't know their wallet)? Is there some kind of optional order reference / comment field in a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is for the online shop to provide unique bitcoin addresses for each customer.

Bob clicks to buy item A and then fills out a quick form with his shipping information, after completion he is prompted to send 1 BTC to bitcoin address X. Alice at the same time clicks to buy item B and fills out a form and she is prompted to send her payment to address Y.  If address X receives funds, the shop owner will know that Bob paid, and Alice did not.

Comment: Address reuse is bad in general anyway. Don't ruin your customers' privacy.

Comment: Or rather, when payment arrives on the address you gave to Bob, you know that Bob's *bill* was paid. You don't know (and shouldn't care) whether it was Bob himself who paid.

Comment: Yes, that is an important distinction. All we care is which invoice/bill is paid, not which individual made the payment.